# Tensorflow serving compilation with CUDA 9 for aws new p3 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I was able to recompile Tensorflow from the Amazon's modified sources (provided in new their new deep learning AMI).

I am now trying to compile tf serving with that Tensorflow "fork" but I am getting that error:

```
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/98acb40d8921d865487eab808ed364b2/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/nccl/BUILD:68:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/nccl:nccl_kernels':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_rewrite.cc':
  '/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/98acb40d8921d865487eab808ed364b2/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/optimization_registry.h'
  '/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/98acb40d8921d865487eab808ed364b2/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device_set.h'
  '/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/98acb40d8921d865487eab808ed364b2/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device.h'
  '/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/98acb40d8921d865487eab808ed364b2/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/graph/types.h'
  '/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/98acb40d8921d865487eab808ed364b2/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/graph/costmodel.h'
  '/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/98acb40d8921d865487eab808ed364b2/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/graph/node_builder.h'
INFO: Elapsed time: 20.377s, Critical Path: 19.47s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Some more info: I'm using the master branch of Tensorflow serving (commit `7a349752c2cbbe741edb91c6c6be1c571e91a5fb`) and Bazel release 0.7.0.

I also made a small change to `tools/bazel.rc` to resolve another compilation error:

```
# git diff tools/bazel.rc 
diff --git a/tools/bazel.rc b/tools/bazel.rc
index 9397f97..28476f3 100644
--- a/tools/bazel.rc
+++ b/tools/bazel.rc
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-build:cuda --crosstool_top=@org_tensorflow//third_party/gpus/crosstool
+build:cuda --crosstool_top=@local_config_cuda//crosstool:toolchain
 build:cuda --define=using_cuda=true --define=using_cuda_nvcc=true

 build --force_python=py2
```

Any idea what is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i usually disable NCCL since it never seems to build properly:

https://github.com/PipelineAI/pipeline/blob/6261c4f31105e40ab8b24ccc7834f9181f4e5aaf/package/tensorflow/16d39e9-d690fdd/Dockerfile.full-gpu#L160

```
RUN \
  cd $TENSORFLOW_SERVING_HOME \
  # Remove NCCL since it isn't building properly
  && sed -i.bak '/nccl/d' tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/BUILD \
  && bazel build -c opt --config=cuda \
      --verbose_failures \
      --spawn_strategy=standalone --genrule_strategy=standalone \
      --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both --copt=-msse4.1 --copt=-msse4.2 \
      --crosstool_top=@local_config_cuda//crosstool:toolchain \
       tensorflow_serving/... \
  && chmod a+x bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server \
  && cp bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server /usr/local/bin/ \
  && bazel clean --expunge
```